# MySQL update query in PHP and get multiple ids returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to perform a mysql UPDATE query and then get an array of ids that were effected in the change.

This is my update query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET deleted='1' WHERE id='$id' OR foo='$foo' OR bar='$bar'");
```

I know that I can do something like this to get the created id from an INSERT query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id,foo,bar) VALUES ('$id','$foo','$bar')");

$newid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Sidenote - Please use PDO or MySQLi as MySQL_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Your queries are open to SQL injections.

Comment: @Daan I do all the escaping before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MySQL has anything like the `OUTPUT` or `RETURNING` clauses that other databases support.  You can get the list of `id`s by running a `select` *before* the `update`:

```
create table temp_table ids_to_update as 
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE (deleted <> '1' or deleted is null) and *id='$id' OR foo='$foo' OR bar='$bar');
```

Note that MySQL doesn't do an update when the value doesn't change.  Hence the first condition -- which you may or may not find important.

Then, to ensure integrity (in the event of intervening transactions that change the data), you can do:

```
update table t join
       temp_table tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set deleted = '1';
```

You could also wrap the two queries in a single transaction, but I think using a temp table to store the `id`s is probably easier.